# Exercise from Stein's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Exercise 9 in chapter 3:

Let $F$ be a closed subset in $\mathbb{R}$, and $\delta(x)$ is the distance from $x$ to $F$, that is,
$$\delta(x)=\inf\{|x-y|:y\in F\}$$
Clearly, $\delta(x+y)\leq |y|$ whenever $x\in F$. Prove the more refined estimate
$$\delta(x+y)/|y|=o(|y|)$$
for a.e. $x\in F$.

That is $\delta(x+y)/|y|\rightarrow0$.

[Hint: Assume that $x$ is a poit of density of F].

My question is why set $F$ has to be a closed set? since I didn't use the this condition in my proof.

My idea is like this:

Suppose $y>0$, let $I=[x,x+y]$.

If $\delta(x+y)\leq m(F^c\cap I)$, then
$$\frac{\delta(x+y)}{|y|}\leq \frac{m(F^c\cap I)}{|y|}=1-\frac{m(F\cap I)}{m(I)}\rightarrow0$$

Since for any $z\in F\cap I$, we must have
$$d(x+y,z)\geq \delta(x+y)$$
then there is an interval of length $\delta(x+y)$ that is an subset of $F^c\cap I$ .

Comment: Without your proof it's hard to say anything. However, try to prove the same fact for $F$ - an open interval. Then, by using the fact that all open sets in $\Bbb R$ are at most countable union of open intervals, prove the same for an arbitrary open set. If it still works, then indeed the hypothesis of closedness is not necessary.

Comment: What is $m$ now?

Comment: the lebesgue measure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hypothesis that $F$ is closed is not necessary. However, note that the distance from a set is the same as the distance from its closure. By passing from $F$ to its closure   we lose no generality, and in fact make a stronger statement because the estimate is claimed to hold a.e. on a larger set.

One proof I like: the function $\delta$ is Lipschitz, therefore differentiable a.e. (it has bounded variation on finite intervals). In particular, it is differentiable at a.e. point of $F$. But  every point of $F$ is a point of minimum for $\delta$. So the derivative of $\delta$ is $0$ whenever it exists.

If you want to argue in terms of density, I think it's easier to do the contrapositive. Namely, assume that there is a sequence $y_k\to 0$ such that $\delta(x+y_k)\ge \epsilon |y_k|$, with fixed $\epsilon>0$, and show that $F$ does not have density $1$ at $x$. Reason: there's a hole of size $2\epsilon |y_k|$ at $x+y_k$.   So, the intersection of $F$ with $[x-2|y_k|,x+2|y_k|]$ has measure at most $2|y_k|(1-\epsilon)$, which is not enough to have density $1$.

Comment: I also like the proof that uses a.e. differentiability of $\delta$.